# phpMyAdmin, Can't create a relation, Error: "relational features disabled"

Tags: database, phpmyadmin

I made an account on Godaddy recently to host my website and they also had an option to build a database with the hosting services. It's a standard phpMyAdmin set up, except when I try to create a relation between two tables it comes up with the following error

> Error: Relational features disabled!

It has never happened to me before and I have no idea how to enable the relational features and actually connect those two tables 
I set Account_id in the main table as a primary key and I've set the the Account_id on the User table as an Index key.

[image: Database Image <<]

Does anyone know how to enable those features.?

Comment: What storage engine is used by the two tables? MyISAM, InnoDB, Memory, etc? Also, which phpMyAdmin version are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure both of the tables have the InnoDB engine selected.