# Ampps phpMyAdmin - Error: Relational features are disabled

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I want to create a relation between two MySQL tables in phpMyAdmin, but I get an error "Relational Features Are Disabled". Is there a workaround?

I am working on Ampps. Versions are phpMyAdmin 4.9.1, MySQL v8.0.18.

I checked several similar questions on SO. Suggested solution is to have both tables set to InnoDB. But I already did that and the problem persists. Below are threads I checked:

[phpMyAdmin, Can't create a relation, Error: "relational features disabled"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33570336/phpmyadmin-cant-create-a-relation-error-relational-features-disabled)

[phpmyadmin Error: Relational features are disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34183240/phpmyadmin-error-relational-features-are-disabled)

Comment: Is your table structure simple enough to paste the SQL here? Can you get to the relational features if you use a different database on the same server? What happens if you try your table structure on the phpMyAdmin demo server at http://demo.phpmyadmin.net/master (username root with a blank password)?